# Reversing an array Query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have an array of size N and I have given 2 types of query

1 L R Reverse all element from [L,R]
2 L Find the  value at index L.

```
Example: [1,2,3,4,5]
1 2 4   -> [1,4,3,2,5]
1 4 5   -> [1,4,3,5,2]
2 5    -> 2
```

**Q**-Number of Query
**Q<=10^5 and N<=10^5**
Straight Forward Solution will be **O(Q*N)** which will be Quite slow, how to make it faster can segment tree can be used ?

Comment: Yes. Segment tree is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @vish4071 how exactly? could you post an answer? :)

Comment: @vish4071 can you explain how to use segment tree in this

Comment: @svs any help !!! on  the use of segment tree

Comment: Anyway you will have a tradeoff between query of type 1(Q1), and query of type 2(Q2) run-time. In the naive solution Q1 will take O(n), and Q2 will take O(1). What exactly do you want to minimize?

Comment: @user5349222 I'm sorry but I don't think this could be solved with segment trees. tried to follow some idea but nothing came up. `David Eisenstat` seems to have to right solution check it up

Comment: @svs i am solving some random    Query problems  which uses `BIT` and `Segment Tree` so this idea can in my mind how to tackle this type of Query

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the segment tree algorithm looks like.

This can be done in time O((n + q) log n) using decorated splay trees. Each node decoration consists of a descendant count and a bit that, when set, implicitly flips the entire subtree. To query, use the descendant counts to navigate to the proper node. To reverse from `u` to `v`, splay `u` to the root, detach its left subtree `u.L`, splay `v` to the root, detach its right subtree `v.R`, invert the flip bits on all of `u.L`, `v`, `v.R`, reattach `u.L` to the field from which `v.R` came, splay `u`, reattach `v.R` similarly.

```
Key: ? denotes an anonymous node
     ^ denotes a subtree


   u
  / \
u.L  ?
 ^  / \
   v   ?
   ^   ^


u.L    v
 ^    / \
     u  v.R
      \  ^
       ?
       ^


v.R    v     # v's flip bit is inverted
 ^    / \
     u  u.L  # so is u.L's, for no effect on u.L
      \  ^
       ?
       ^


   u
  / \
v.R  v
 ^  / \
   ?  u.L
   ^   ^
```

Comment: 1) sorry but how do you exactly perform the second type of query? can't see it. 2) do you store the index of an element in the tree node? 3) by `decorated` you mean augmented, meaning it stores additional information different than left, right child? 4) do know similar applications of splay trees? they seem like very powerful tool

Comment: @svs 1. Added an diagram. 2. Yes, each node contains a data value. 3. Yes. 4. There are a bunch of applications in the original paper by Sleator--Tarjan.

Comment: what I don't get is why we end up with having `u.R` to be `u`'s left child. I find problem in  the following: let's query for something  with index less than `u`, lets say `p < u`. At this point `u` is the root and we see that `p < u`. Also the `u`'s inversion flag is false meaning we should go left. But when we go left we go in the subtree `v.R` in which every element is  greater than `v` which in itself is greater than `u`. That mean that we will extract something `> u` but we wanted `p < u`.

Comment: @svs If it helps, I usually think about it in terms of splitting sequences, reversing whole sequences, and concatenating sequences together. I've actually implemented this, so I promise it's possible.

Comment: I believe it's possible but don't see why `v.R` should be `u`'s left child and `u.L` - `v`' s right. Shouldn't be the opposite?

Comment: And the flag signals you if you should turn left or right, right? If it's off you go left and on right ( presuming that we are searching in the left subtree)

Comment: @svs The flag flips over the whole subtree, so since `u`'s flag is inverted from what it was (via `v`'s being inverted), the whole diagram is interpreted flipped over (except `u.L` and `v.R` have their original orientations, being flipped over themselves).

Comment: doesn't those steps actually break the `symmetric order` of the tree. `symmetric order: If x is a node containing an item i, the left subtree of x contains only items less than i and the right subtree only items greater than i`. At the end the left subtree of the root u is v.R whose elements are all greater than u - the root itself?

Comment: It is not binary search tree, it is binary tree.

Comment: You can use a simple binary tree with a bit at every node that idicates reversed or not. If reversed, your traveling for Q2 will be from right to left.

Comment: @barak1412 I don't think it's that easy. Could you post an answer with an explanation?

Comment: I think your last tree (in the figure) should be `[u, [u.L, ...], [v, [?, ...], [v.R, ...]]]`

Comment: I will try to think more about the problem, and when i have time formalize the answer

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Sorry for bothering but are you sure your last tree  in the figure is correct? Shouldn't it be `[u, [u.L, ...], [v, [?, ...], [v.R, ...]]]`?