# Is there any fastest approach to reverse the range of elements in an array consisting of two types of elements?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, range, reverse

I have an array, let say:
2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2

(the array consists of two unique integers, repeated)

Given `L` and `R` (denotes the range within the array).
Is there any fastest approach to reverse the elements of array in range `L` to `R`?
currently, I am doing it in O(n).

For above example, if L=2 and R=5, the new array will be,
2, `3, 2, 3, 3`, 3, 3, 2

I went through this solution:
[Reversing an array Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966228/reversing-an-array-query)

But wanted to whether there is any other approach apart from `decorated splay trees` ?

Comment: `O(n/2)` is the same as `O(0.5 n)` which is the same as `O(n)`.

Comment: can it be more optimized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is faster way (due to **swap** operation) but you can use another data structure.

The idea here I guess is to use kind of double-linked list with operation **go through** which would pass the list by visiting

- *next* sibling if the *next* is not *before*
- *before* sibling if the *next* is *before*

in a pseudo-code something like:

```
class Node
{
    Node before, next;
}

void goThrough(Node root, Node currentNode)
{
     //some actions here

     if( root.next != null || root.next != currentNode )
     {
         goThrough( root.next );
     }

     if( root.before != null )
     {
         goThrough( root.before );
     }
}
```

then the reversing range would be just about changing **next/before** fields at the start and end of range - which actually makes **O(1)**